# Printer goes offline after every 4 hours

Tags: cups

Need help. I am using Raspberry Pi and have CUPS running. The challenge I have is the Printer goes offline after every 4 or 4 hours…is there a way that I can set CUPS to restart after every 3 hours?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can configure your Raspberry Pi to automatically restart the CUPS service at specific intervals using a combination of a systemd timer and service unit. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to set this up:

1. **Create a systemd service unit for CUPS**:

   First, create a systemd service unit file for CUPS if it doesn't already exist. Typically, it's already available on most Linux systems, but you can create one if needed.

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/cups.service
   ```

   Add the following content to the `cups.service` file:

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=CUPS Scheduler

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l
   Restart=always
   ```

   Save the file and exit the text editor.
2. **Create a systemd timer unit for CUPS**:

   Now, create a systemd timer unit file that specifies when to trigger the CUPS service restart.

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/cups.timer
   ```

   Add the following content to the `cups.timer` file. This example will restart CUPS every 3 hours.

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Timer to restart CUPS every 3 hours

   [Timer]
   OnBootSec=3h
   OnUnitActiveSec=3h
   Unit=cups.service

   [Install]
   WantedBy=timers.target
   ```

   Save the file and exit the text editor.
3. **Enable and start the timer**:

   Enable the timer unit and start it:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl enable cups.timer
   sudo systemctl start cups.timer
   ```
4. **Verify the timer status**:

   You can check the status of the timer to ensure it's active and running with:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl status cups.timer
   ```

Now, your Raspberry Pi should automatically restart the CUPS service every 3 hours as configured. This should help keep your printer online. You can adjust the `OnBootSec` and `OnUnitActiveSec` values in the `cups.timer` file to set a different time interval for service restarts if needed.